# Nest js How to download file from external link and convert it to buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I want to download xml file from external Url and convert it to buffer

I can't find a solution yet

Comment: What HTTP module are you using to make the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to download the full buffer stream.

```
const response = await this.httpService.axiosRef({
  url,
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
});
const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary');
```